# Gmail Batch Requests - queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail-api

Is there a way to have multiple queries in one request to the gmail api?

I want to get a list and then later get messages from a list of email addresses. Now the messages.list quota is 5, so I was trying to use batch request. However, is there a way to add multiple email addresses as queries in one single batch request to gmail api?

Any guidance will be helpful.

Thank you!
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).